# MVVM Hierarchical Navigation tutorial StackOverFlow exception

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, uwp

I'm trying to reproduce a MVVM tutorial for WPF but applying it to UWP. But I've done everything in the tutorial I believe right the exact same code shown at the tutorial.

But when I ran the code I kept getting a `StackOverflowException` which is caused because the MainPageView keeps initializing again and again, until the exception is thrown.

The thing is I'm kinda knew at MVVM and I wish to master it, so can somebody please explain me why am I getting this?

I'll leave the code of each one of my classes and views.

This is my MainPageView.Xaml:

```
<Page
x:Class="MVVMHierarchiesDemo.MainPageView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MVVMHierarchiesDemo"
xmlns:views="using:MVVMHierarchiesDemo.Views"
xmlns:viewmodel="using:MVVMHierarchiesDemo.ViewModel"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<!--Anytime the current view model is set to an instance of a CustomerListViewModel,
it will render out a CustomerListView with the ViewModel is hooked up. It’s an order ViewModel,
it'll render out OrderView and so on.

We now need a ViewModel that has a CurrentViewModel property and some logic and commanding
to be able to switch the current reference of ViewModel inside the property.-->
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:MainPageView/>
</Page.DataContext>

<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomerTemplate" x:DataType="viewmodel:CustomerListViewModel">
        <views:CustomerListView/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="OrderTemplate" x:DataType="viewmodel:OrderViewModel">
        <views:OrderView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="NavBar"
          Grid.Row="0">
        <Button Content="Customers"
                Command="{Binding NavCommand}"
                CommandParameter="customers"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="0"/>

        <Button Content="Orders"
                Command="{Binding NavCommand}"
                CommandParameter="orders"
                Grid.Column="2"
                Grid.Row="0"/>
    </Grid>

    <Grid x:Name="MainContent"
          Grid.Row="1">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"/>
    </Grid>      
</Grid>
</Page>
```

This is my code-behind `MainPageView.xaml.cs` - here is where the `StackoverflowException` is thrown in the constructor it keeps calling it.

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace MVVMHierarchiesDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPageView : Page
    {
        public MainPageView()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }        
    }
}
```

This is my `BindableBase.cs` as the tutorial shows:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace MVVMHierarchiesDemo
{
    /*The main idea behind this class is to encapsulate the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
     * and provide helper methods to the derived class so that they can easily trigger the appropriate notifications.
     * Following is the implementation of BindableBase class.*/
    public class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        protected virtual void SetProperty<T>(ref T member, T val, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (object.Equals(member, val))
                return;

            member = val;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }
}
```

This is `MyCommand.cs` or better known as the relay command pattern:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MVVMHierarchiesDemo
{
    /* Now it's time to actually start doing some view switching using our CurrentViewModel property.
     * We just need some way to drive the setting of this property. And we're going to make it so that
     * the end user can command going to the customer list or to the order view. First add a new class
     * in your project which will implement the ICommand interface. Following is the implementation of
     * ICommand interface.*/
    public class MyCommand<T> : ICommand
    {
        Action<T> _TargetExecuteMethod;
        Func<T, bool> _TargetCanExecuteMethod;

        public MyCommand(Action<T> targetExecuteMethod)
        {
            _TargetExecuteMethod = targetExecuteMethod;
        }

        public MyCommand(Action<T> targetExecuteMethod, Func<T,bool> targetCanExecuteMethod)
        {
            _TargetExecuteMethod = targetExecuteMethod;
            _TargetCanExecuteMethod = targetCanExecuteMethod;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = delegate { };

        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (_TargetCanExecuteMethod != null)
            {
                T tparam = (T)parameter;
                return _TargetCanExecuteMethod(tparam);
            }

            if (_TargetExecuteMethod != null)
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
        {
            if(_TargetExecuteMethod!=null)
            {
                T tparam = (T)parameter;
                _TargetExecuteMethod(tparam);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my usercontrol for OrdersView.xaml:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MVVMHierarchiesDemo.Views.OrderView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MVVMHierarchiesDemo.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Order View"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is my user control CustomerListView.xaml:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MVVMHierarchiesDemo.Views.CustomerListView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MVVMHierarchiesDemo.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Customer List View"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is my OrderViewModel:

```
namespace MVVMHierarchiesDemo.ViewModel
{
    /*Derive all of your ViewModels from BindableBase class.*/
    public class OrderViewModel : BindableBase
    {
    }
}
```

This is my CustomerViewModel:

```
namespace MVVMHierarchiesDemo.ViewModel
{
    /*Derive all of your ViewModels from BindableBase class.*/
    public class CustomerListViewModel : BindableBase
    {
    }
}
```

Finally this is my MainPageViewModel:

```
namespace MVVMHierarchiesDemo.ViewModel
{
    /*Derive all of your ViewModels from BindableBase class.*/
    public class MainPageViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            NavCommand = new MyCommand<string>(OnNavigation);
        }

        private CustomerListViewModel _customerListViewModel = new CustomerListViewModel();

        private OrderViewModel _orderViewModel = new OrderViewModel();

        private BindableBase _currentViewModel;

        public BindableBase CurrentViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return _currentViewModel;
            }

            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _currentViewModel, value);
            }
        }

        public MyCommand<string> NavCommand { get; private set; }

        private void OnNavigation(string destination)
        {
            switch (destination)
            {
                case "orders":
                    {
                        CurrentViewModel = _orderViewModel;
                        break;
                    }
                case "customers":
                default:
                    CurrentViewModel = _customerListViewModel;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and lastly I think the MainPageView is the one causing the infinite looping but I don't understand why?

If somebody could be so kind to tell me what I am doing wrong on UWP?

Also I could use MVVM Light or MVVMCross I'm not interested on those solutions I want to learn MVVM by hand and later on i might check those frameworks.

Comment: **Typo alert:** it's a **hierarchy** - not a "heirachy" as you kept using ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because in your `MainPageView.xaml` you have this:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:MainPageView/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

So every `MainPageview` creates a nested `MainPageView` as its `DataContext`. These are created until you blow the stack.

I think you meant to put a `MainPageViewModel` in here.

Comment: Damn, you were right!!! Maaan, how couldnt i saw it. I'm sorry dont like to copy paste code, I prefered to retype it myself. I guess i was too tired that i didnt see that obvious mistake. I was trying to put MainPageViewModel.
Thanks for lending me your eagle eye!!!